# Probability concerning Normal Distributions independent of one another

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

A team comprised of 10 individuals are tasked to put balls inside a box. Suppose that each individual’s contribution is normally distributed and has a mean of 12 balls and standard deviation of  1 ball. The team wins only if the total number of balls they put is less than 100 balls. Assuming that each of their contribution is independent, What is the probability that they win?

Attempt:
Using the formula of z= (x̄- μ) / σ. I find the probability that x is less than 10 which is 0.0275 for z=-2. I then multiply the value by 10 leading to an answer of 0.275. Is this a correct way of approaching the problem or should I be computing it as a whole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention that the distribution is gaussian.  Assuming this, the total contribution is gaussian with mean

$$\underbrace{12+12+\dots +12}_{\text{10 times}}=120$$

and variance

$$\underbrace{1^2+1^2+\dots +1^2}_{\text{10 times}}=10$$

---

If normality is not assumed you have to use another way, i.e. Chebishev's inequality

Comment: I apologize. Yes it is assumed that it is normally distributed. Why do we not add the probabilities themselves ? How is it valid that we multiply the mean and standard dev by the number of people?

Comment: @Fanoye because $P(X+Y<a+b)\ne P(X<a)+P(Y<b)$. The total contribution is gaussian with mean 120 and st dev $\sqrt{10}$. I did not multiply mean and st dev but I summed individual means and variances.  It is not the same

Comment: Alright. May I know why do we add up our variances as opposed to the standard deviation? Is there any theorem regarding this ? I apologize for asking many questions

Comment: @Fanoye it's a property of gaussian law. Sum of independent gaussians is still gaussian with mean sum of individual means and variance sum of individual variances. In your case the result doesn't change as st dev=var but in general it is different

Comment: I see!! So solving for the probability is (100-120)/ sqrt(10)? This leads to a z=-6.32. So the probability they win is zero right?

Comment: @Fanoye right. You can mark my answer as accepted if it has been useful for you...